# How do I go through pictures (like a slide show) just by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, slideshow

I'm learning to use HTML, CSS and Javascript and I can't get this code to work. I am working on a slideshow page, where you can navigate through the slides with buttons.

I get for how to move to the next image and how to go back one, using arrays. But how should I code the forward, backwards and pause button? (forward and backwards is supposed to make the slide change every 1 second in one direction). If you're wondering, I have a 0.jpg there just as filler.

Here is my code so far:

```js
var count = 0;

var pics = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];
var arrayLength = pics.length;

function slideshow() {

  count++;
  if (count > arrayLength - 1) {
    count = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById('num').src = pics[count];

}

function Next() {
  count++;
  if (count > arrayLength - 1) {
    count = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('num').src = pics[count];
}

function Back() {
  count--;
  if (count < 1) {
    count = arrayLength - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('num').src = pics[count];
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Slide Show</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <img id="num" src="0.jpg">
</center>

<center>
  <input type="button" name=btnBackward value="Backward" onClick="Backward()" />
  <input type="button" name=btnBack value="Back" onClick="Back()" />
  <input type="button" name=btnPause value="Pause" onClick="Pause()" />
  <input type="button" name=btnNext value="Next" onClick="Next()" />
  <input type="button" name=btnFoward value="Foward" onClick="Foward()" />
</center>
```

Comment: `<center>` is not an HTML element, and you should not be using `onClick` in modern code! Aside from that, what have you tried so far to get the Forward and Back functions working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after your code, it may work, **the point is in setInterval()** usage. You got error on your button press, you got there "Foward()" instead of "Forward()".
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is manual for that. I think it will work this way.

```
var interval = 0;
function Pause() {
 if (interval!=0) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = 0;
 } 
}

function Forward() {
 Pause();
  interval = setInterval( function() { Next() }, 2000);
}

function Backward() {
 Pause();
  interval = setInterval( function() { Back() }, 2000);
}
```

Please use functions names with lowercase first character since they are class names.

You should change your "Back()" function (because zeros aren't loading.) to:

```
function Back() {
  count--;
  document.getElementById('num').src = pics[count];
  if (count < 1) {
    count = arrayLength - 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this context, `function() { Next(); }` is the same thing as `Next`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you have to do is make two functions for forward and backwards with setTimeout on them. And they will perform looping your functions next and back.
Like that:

```
function forward() {
    Next();
    setTimeout(forward, 1000);
}
function backwards() {
    Back();
    setTimeout(backwards, 1000);
}
```

P.S. better to write function names from the letter in a lower case. In upper case it mean classes. And better to use verbs. Good luck :)